# Same IPs are showing in stack monitoring

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I didn't get a response from elasticsearch forum.I don't know is it a bug or not but it was working fine earlier.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/same-ips-are-showing-in-stack-monitoring/295803

Comment: Your question doesn't mention what "earlier" means? Did you restart your cluster, did you upgrade it? What changed between the time it worked ok and now?

Comment: it was working fine in 7.10 then we upgrade to 7.13 we didn't notice this same ip issue that time and then we finally upgrade to 7.16 but unfortunately issue is not resolved.

Comment: hey @Val remember that i've encounter this problem from 7.13 version.I am running 11 nodes of cluster 3 master 6 data nodes and 2 coordinate nodes.I have install metricbeat in master nodes only.When i upgrade cluster from 7.10 to 7.13 first i upgrade master nodes and then data nodes coordinate nodes while upgrading each node i restart node one by one

Comment: i remove previous of metricbeat and install and setup latest metricbeat.